# Jquery Ajax call inside Jquery Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm loading a part of a page using ajax with this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn_new').live('click',function(){
            var parameter = 1;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "new_message.php",
                data: {
                        parameter:parameter,
                },
                success: function(msg)
                {
                    $("#lib_container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                    {
                        $("#lib_container").html(msg);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Inside the lib_container div I have a text input with this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function searchUsers(str) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "users_ajax.php",
            data: {
                    search:str
            },
            success: function(msg)
            {
                //console.log(msg);
                //$("#users_lst").html(msg.response);
                $("#users_lst").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                {
                    $("#users_lst").html(msg);
                });

            }

        });
}
</script>
```

When I load some text in the input, the second ajax script loads the msg variable in the div but then also reloaded the lib_container div.
I've tried many ways to prevent the lib_container ajax trigger but it was in vain. Just putting the input in new page works correctly.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: why are you setting an ajaxComplete callback when your ajax request is already done? when the success function runs that is the end of the request you already have your data no need to set ajaxComplete.

Comment: Every time you call `.ajaxComplete()` you're establishing another handler for _all_ AJAX calls.

Comment: BTW, `.live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, and removed in 1.9. Unless you're using an old version of jQuery, you should recode it using `.on`.

Comment: The first charge doesn't work without the ajaxcomplete. I don't know how to do the first charge differently, but I can't run this way the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you are registering a new ajaxComplete handler every time you get a successful response from the ajax call. Since it seems like you want to update the html, I'm not sure why you need those ajaxComplete handlers anyway.

Try it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn_new').live('click',function(){
        var parameter = 1;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "new_message.php",
            data: { parameter:parameter },
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#lib_container").html(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And by the same token:

```
function searchUsers(str) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "users_ajax.php",
        data: { search:str },
        success: function(msg) {
            $("#users_lst").html(msg);
        }

    });
}
```

On another note, `.live` is deprecated and you really ought to be using ajax promises rather than a `success` callback. See [the jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com) for more info on that.

Comment: Thanks, you've been very helpful. I deleted the ajaxComplete and it worked correctly